# Error 400 on submission request on job that ran before

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

since today in the morning I am always getting the following error while running a job on IBM Sydney

"'Error submitting job: '400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api-qcon.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q-afrl/Groups/air-force-lab/Projects/quantum-sim/Jobs. Topology without kind established., {"topologyId":"5f61b942174c232ece451d1f"}, Error code: 2614.''

The job script ran fine until yesterday at night and has not been altered at all.
Can you please tell me what is going on ? This is also not the error that I have seen in previous slack questions

Answer (score 4):

This was due to temporary issue on IBM side. If you try to resubmit your job it should work as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francois. Yes indeed the job now seems to run as before